# Создать если нет или обновить если есть

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица. Мне нужно вставить в неё строку, если её нет или же обновить её если запись уже существует.

Пока что я делаю так: пытаюсь получить по одному из полей нужные мне данные, потом проверяю, вернулось ли что-либо, если да, то обновляю, если нет, то создаю новую запись.

Comment: `on duplicate update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и написал товарищ в комментарии - Вам поможет [on duplicate update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). А именно:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`,`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `a` = ?, `b` = ? `c` = ?;
```

Эта "штука" срабатывает если по вставляемым полям есть совпадения в [уникальном ключе](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html).
Также по первой ссылке посмотрите еще синтаксис с использованием `VALUES(`column`)` в update-части.

Возможно в какой-то момент возникнет ситуация, когда нужно будет вставить значение "а если с таким ключом уже есть - то ничего не делать" - тогда нужно будет использовать вместо этого `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...`